# only using plus operator

Tags: php

If Variable 1,2 and 3 have the values 3,5 and 7 respectively,
select the correct sequence of equations that will result in placing values 
12 in variable 1 
and
15 in variable 3
(Use only ADD operator)

```
    $var1 = 3;
$var2 = 5;
$var3 = 7;

//anser 12 
echo $var1 = $var2 + $var3;


echo $var3 = $var3 + $var1;
//here i need to ge 15 for var 3 
//but var1 value now 12 so anser is 19 (wrong)
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you're going to ask us to do your homework for you, you might consider at least making an attempt first.

Comment: at least try something before asking for help...

Comment: Having your homework done by Stack Overflow kinda defeats its purpose, doesn't it?

Comment: I tried this for hours please help me ..

Comment: and where are the sequences you have to choose from? :)

Comment: If I try something for hours, I have pages of code, that does something, just not correctly. Post it here, we will help. We will **not** solve it for you.

Comment: Post your code(try) here, otherwise they(we) think you are not tried anything so far, and then any of us can't help you..

Comment: Are you looking for this ? `$var1 = 3;
$var2 = 5;
$var3 = 7;

$var1 = $var2 + $var3;
$var3 = $var1 + $var2 + $var3;`

Comment: is there a way using += operator for this 
but i search, it is same like + oprator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var1 = 3;
$var2 = 5;
$var3 = 7;


$var2 = $var3+$var2; # 12
$var3 = $var2+$var1; # 15
$var1 = $var2; # 12
```

Comment: wow that is so easy 
I"m a idiot :(
Thanks for helping....!